# Docker swarm order: stop-first

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have one server manager-worker.
Deploying to stack compose file with this config

```
    healthcheck:
        test: "curl --fail localhost:10001/api/instance/code || exit 1"
        interval: 60s
        retries: 5
        start_period: 20s
        timeout: 10s
    deploy:
        update_config:
            parallelism: 1
            order: start-first
            failure_action: rollback
            delay: 10s
        rollback_config:
            parallelism: 0
            order: stop-first
        restart_policy:
            condition: any
            delay: 5s
            max_attempts: 3
            window: 120s
```

Desirable behavior it starting then waiting until healthy then stop old one but it shutting down old one before new is healthy.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the complete stack. You cannot do "start-first" if that would cause a deadlock waiting for resources - such as ports. i.e. a host mode published port can prevent this, or any other constraint that prevents two instances running on the same node, with insufficient other free available nodes to run the new task.